# What happened to people who committed crimes (such as killing) in SAO?

Tags: sword-art-online

There are many people in SAO who committed crimes (such as doing PK), yet managed to survive until the end of the game. What happened to them after that? Did they go to trial and get sentenced to prison?

If that's the case, what about people (like Kirito) who killed others involuntarily in self-defense? Were they exempted from trial?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the end of the ALO arc in the novel, where Kirito thinks about his school and the policy to avoid using in-game names:

> In this special «school», the students were players who had been in middle or high school before the SAO incident. Those orange players with a serious history of murder were undergoing more than one year of counseling that included treatment and observation. People like me who attacked others for self-defense, were inquired without leaving a criminal record like theft or blackmail.

Comment: i think you should put the spoiler mark regarding the school.